# Why not create a window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Why not create a window? What am I doing wrong? May need to add some permissions?

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('popup.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    }
  });
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title : "create a window",
  contexts : ["image"],
  type: "normal"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of [extension APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) includes `contextMenus`, while the list of [app APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) does not. Conversely, from those same lists, apps have access to `app.window`, while extensions do not.

If your code is part of an extension, it cannot use `app.window`; if it is an app, it cannot use `contextMenus`.

Instead, perhaps you can simply make do with `window.open`.